# How to optimize a "bit stream" to work on chunks of input in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, encoding, binary, bit-manipulation

I asked a similar question on how to work with Uint8Array and read and write bits from it, and got a wonderful [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/254692/168199) showing this as the final result:

```js
function createBitOrder(fromLeft, bits) {
    const bitMasks = [];
    var i = bits;
    while (i-- > 0) { bitMasks.push(fromLeft ? (1 << i) : (1 << (bits - 1 - i))) }
    return bitMasks;
}
function BitStream(mask) {
    var pos = 0, buf = [];
    const maskOut = mask.map(v => 0xFF ^ v);
    return {
        set pos(p) { pos = p },
        set buf(data) { buf = data },
        get bit() { return (buf[pos >> 3] & mask[pos++ % 8]) ? 1 : 0 },
        set bit(val) { 
            const byte = pos >> 3, bit = pos ++ % 8;
            buf[byte] = (buf[byte] & maskOut[bit]) + (val ? mask[bit] : 0);
        },
        writeTo(stream, bits) { while (bits-- > 0) { stream.bit = this.bit } },
        clear(bits) { while (bits-- > 0) { this.bit = 0 } },
    };
}

// replacement functions
function BitMovers() {
    const mask = createBitOrder(true, 8);  // high to low
    const read = BitStream(mask);
    const write = BitStream(mask);
    return {
        moveBits(fromBuf, fromBit, numBits, toBuf, toBit) {
            read.buf = fromBuf;
            write.buf = toBuf;
            read.pos = fromBit;
            write.pos = toBit;
            read.writeTo(write, numBits);
        },
        clearBits(buf, fromBit, numBits) {
            write.buf = buf;
            write.pos = fromBit;
            write.clear(numBits);
        },
    }
}

const movers = BitMovers();
const bufA = [255,0,255,0];
const bufB = [0,0,0,0];
movers.moveBits(bufA, 4, 8, bufB, 20);
movers.clearBits(bufB, 1, 6);

const readStream = BitStream(createBitOrder(true, 8));
const writeStream = BitStream(createBitOrder(true, 8));

function bufGet(bufA, readPos, bits, bufB, writePos) {
    readStream.buf = bufA;     // set buffers
    writeStream.buf = bufB;
    readStream.pos = readPos;  // set read and write positions
    writeStream.pos = writePos;
    while (bits-- > 0) { writeStream.bit = readStream.bit }
}

const f11 = [0b10111001, 0b10111001, 0b10111001];
const f12 = [0, 0, 0];
bufGet(f11, 1, 16, f12, 0);
```

This teaches me exactly what I needed about how to properly deal with, well, "bit streams". I didn't even think of that as a concept, and my solution in that question was far from ideal.

However, **it works on *1 bit at a time*.** This seems to be less than optimal for my situation.

So say I have an *encoding* that is like this:

```
<2-bit-marker>
<8-bit-value>
<32-bit-value>
<arbitrary-multiple-of-2-bit-value>
```

So you would have potentialy:

```
10
10101010
10101010101010101010101010101010
1010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010
```

Always multiples of two in each of them. The first 3 values are metadata on the 4th value, so I need to read the first 2-bit chunk, then read the next 8-bits, then the next 32-bits. Let's say the 32-bit value tells you **how many bits** the following 4th value contains. The 4th value then contains that many bits, padded to be a multiple of 2.

Basically, you would copy that 4th section into a different section of a Uint32Array (or a separate Uint32Array), perhaps even limiting the copied version to chunking the data in *powers of two*. So if you had several megabytes of data in one chunk, it would be copied over and stored in chunks of 4096 bits, let's just say. Could be any power of two, but I don't want to complicate this question too much. The essence is, we must:

1. Copy the 4th section of data to a new place in memory, or a different Uint32Array for all intents and purposes. And,
2. At the same time, process the 4th section, potentially chunking it up (let's say into chunks of max-size 4096 bits). We don't need to include this in the answer, but just want you to know there will be some **processing** happening on the data we receive, that's the gist of it.

So a simple streaming copy operation might not be ideal. But something that streams let's say 32-bits at a time from the 4th chunk, using the size info from the 3rd chunk to know when to stop traversing the 4th chunk, and then micro-processes the 32-bit chunks to make sure we don't go too far or too short at the tail-end... that might work.

How would you do this optimally in JavaScript?

The `BitStream` class above will read *1 bit at a time*, which seems less than ideal. I can see if you had an extremely complicated encoding with odd-numbered bits here and there, it would be advantageous. But what do you think about this example? How would you do it optimally?

Since we don't know how long the 4th segment of data is, we have to read at arbitrary places. So say we have something like this:

```
<2-bit><8-bit><16-bit><48-bit>
<2-bit><8-bit><16-bit><12-bit>
<2-bit><8-bit><16-bit><100000-bit>
<2-bit><8-bit><16-bit><20-bit>
<2-bit><8-bit><16-bit><1000-bit>
<2-bit><8-bit><16-bit><10000-bit>
<2-bit><8-bit><16-bit><64-bit>
```

All compacted into a sequence. What would be a good approach to reading these larger chunks from a `Uint32Array`, and placing them into another part of memory? I am trying to get a sense of what this will look like in the real world, as I am new to bit manipulation best practices.

What would a simple implementation of this above example look like in JavaScript? Alternatively, if you think this 1-bit-at-a-time approach is ideal, then that will work too. I just want to make sure this part of my application is highly optimized because this is a bottleneck, especially with my (linked) ugly implementation of "bit streaming" haha.

Comment: That's a really weird encoding. What hardware are you trying to run this on?

Comment: Do you really need to support different [bit endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Bit_endianness)? Normally that is only relevant for physical layer transmission. All code working on octets uses LSB 0 [bit numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering).

Comment: @Bergi I'm not sure what is weird, can you explain what the weird parts are? Each "chunk" of the first 3 chunks let's assume is read from right to left, the 32-bit chunks being 4 8-bit chunks. The last of the chunks (the 4th chunk) can be arbitrary data (like a PNG or MP3, or some custom thing). I see this no different from file uploading in the browser. Since we are in JS-land, reading 32-bits at a time seems reasonable (for the 4th chunk), so that's why I suggested that, as an optimization.

Comment: Weird insofar as it doesn't seem to have any [proper alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) and is therefore hard/inefficient to address

Comment: Are all encodings "properly aligned" to 8-bits? I thought even things like [TTF fonts](https://github.com/opentypejs/opentype.js/blob/master/src/opentype.js) have 4-bit values here and 3-bit values there (maybe it was _bytes_, eek), are you saying they must be padded to at least 1-byte? (I don't know that many examples of real-world encodings). I thought these types of encoding were meant to be compact and so weren't byte aligned.

Comment: In-memory, generally yes. For transport or long-term storage, they might be compressed.

Comment: This is for transport and long term storage. For memory everything is aligned to 32 on 32-bit machines, and 64 on those machines. But for files I was thinking of storing everything compactly and yet wondering how to process it efficiently. Maybe I will change it to be 8-bit-aligned, but question still stands I guess how to do non-byte-aligned reading optimally like in this situation (even though it is 2-bit aligned haha). My problem is how to go from compact bits in a file to lay it out in 32-bit aligned memory. One bit at a time is too slow.

Comment: Generally, `target[i] = source[j] << offset | source[j+1] >>> (32-offset)`. Every unaligned word is a combination of the respective parts of two aligned words. (Add capping to the length of your segments and you're done. Beware of endianness conversions)

Comment: Memory is cheap, CPU cycles are not.. Pad data to byte boundaries.. Most storage mediums, and many transport protocols compress the data already and padded zeros or ones can be highly compressed so there is no need to save space.You can not compress CPU cycles so a <1% data size increase is worth the 8+ times performance gain

Comment: Well, you can't get any faster than copying one 32-bit entry over at a time. If, when copying, you want to change how the data is aligned to the byte boundaries, then you can't get any faster than two copy operations per 32-bit entry (half goes to one destination byte, the other half to another byte). The bit by bit solution certainly is much more elegant, but if you're really trying to speed it up more, you'll have to sacrifice some elegance. (I tried to show this optimal implementation in my answer to your last question, but I probably didn't explain it well)

Comment: @Bergi can you explain what you mean more with a full example for `target[i] = source[j] << offset | source[j+1] >>> (32-offset)`?

Comment: @LancePollard It's meant to be part of a loop over the two `Uint32Array`s with `i++, j++`, copying unaligned values into aligned locations (or the other way round). Just go through it with pencil and paper to see where each bit ends up.